# Xcursor no included in Yocto SDK

Tags: sdk, yocto, x11

I have been stuck on this for a while now, Xcursor (libXcursor.so and Xcursor.h) is not included in my Yocto(kirkstone) SDK when running the following command:

```
bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk
```

However it is generated (in yocto-tmp/sysroots) when I run:

```
bitbake build-sysroots
```

In my local.conf I have the following:

```
MACHINE ??= 'nitrogen6x'
DISTRO ?= 'fslc-x11'
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " xcursor"
...
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES:append = "dev-pkgs dbg-pkgs staticdev-pkgs"
```

I tried to add:

```
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES:append = " X11 libxcursor xcursor "
```

But this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [How to include GL/gl.h in SDK generate with Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753111/how-to-include-gl-gl-h-in-sdk-generate-with-yocto?rq=2)

I had to add the following:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK += " libxcursor"
```